# curl get the value from out put and run again with that value appended

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, curl

I am getting some data from `curl --silent http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/some-name` However `some-name` is different in each environment. How can I run something like: `curl --silent http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/` get the output (`some-name`) and run it again with that value appended?

Comment: so you want to make two different curl request, one to get the (some-name) variable then append that variable to the end of earlier url and make a new request??

Comment: This seems pretty straight forward. If the output coming from that API is `json` then you can use a program like `jq` to get your security-credentials from your first call into a variable and then just call your second curl. Is there a part of those steps that are causing you issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can do two commands

```sh
ROLE=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials)

SECRET_STUFF=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/$ROLE)
```